# rmarkdown adding blank space around headers when knitting to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

I am encountering a weird issue where when I knit my markdown document to a pdf, some of the headers/figures are having a bunch of line breaks/spaces buffered above and below them (see image below for both code and knit document). I cannot figure out why this is occurring. I have checked the spaces above and below the headers and nearby chunks to make sure they are consistent, as I know this can sometimes cause similar issues, to no avail. There are some headers that are seemingly unaffected, and I tried to copy/paste those over the ones that are, and yet when doing so they also get the breaks added in that space.

When removing the code chunks for my plots, however, these mysterious spacings disappear.

[image: Preview of what the output pdf looks like]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I believe I've solved the issue, and will leave this here in case anyone has similar issues in the future. I believe the buffers are being added around the headers under which the code chunks are placed because the image would otherwise be cutoff or not fit on the page in that location. Since markdown does not want the image to be cut off, it adds a space buffer to make sure it will fit on the page. You can work around this by either changing the size of the image or the location to make sure that it will fully fit on one page without being cut off.

Comment: Please, don't use image to show us your code. Paste your code here directly!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will help us help you if you provided a reproducible example. That means pasting code instead of an image of it, providing some dummy data and, in this particular case, share the header of the .Rmd file

Comment: @patL Sorry, here's a clarification. I couldn't wrap the table in a code chunk as I otherwise would.

Comment: @PavoDive thank you for the reply. Since this is a working manuscript, I don't want to post too much right now. I don't know that dummy data is necessary because my code is otherwise knitting fine, it's seemingly more a general markdown issue. By header here, do you mean the YAML header? I was referring to headers as in level 1 headers like "Results", which is entered as #Results here.

Comment: If we can't reproduce your problem, then we won't be able to figure out what is going wrong. I understand the confidentiality issues, that's why you should work on **dummy data**. And by the header of the file, yes, I do refer to the YAML header.

Comment: @PavoDive I understand that it is difficult to help without a working example in front of you. However, I have been unable to create one in a separate document. I did notice, however, that when I remove the chunks for my two plots, the mysterious spacing goes away. I presume it must have something to do with them, then? I am adding my YAML header and the chunk settings for the figures, and hopefully that will be more helpful? Thank you.